# Interactive tree command

Tags: vim, utilities, tree

Is there any version of `tree` command that displays file structure as a tree structure, but in a way that I can interactively walk trough?

Why do I need it exactly - I am trying to simulate TextMate project drawer using `vim` and splitscreen with `screen` and "interactive" `tree` on the left. But if there is any better way than that, I would also like to hear it.

Comment: You could always run `vim your_dir` and hit `i` three times to list the directories as a tree. From there you can interactively walk through the tree.

Comment: Oh, it seems I don't know everything about `vim`! Thanks! A little question - how do I resize the vim "window"?

Comment: You can **split** the vim window vertically and horizontally with `Ctrl+W+V` and `Ctrl+W+S`, respectively. Anyway, I think what you want here is something like the vim [nerdtree plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658).

Comment: What are the differences between nerdtree and netrw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`nerdtree`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) plugin for `vim` should do just that. It gives you a tree view of your filesystem inside `vim` that can be used interactively. It supports a dozen features such as bookmarking files, syntax highlighting, mouse support, tree filtering and more. Generally, good stuff to have when working on projects that span multiple files and directories.

Comment: Sorry I am accepting your answer 2 years later, I just sort of forgot about it earlier. :)